# ConcurrentModificationException - how to fix?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

There is an application consisting of an activation container in which 2 fragments are replaced (list and details). I get "RuntimeException Caused by: ConcurrentModificationException" from about 0.5 users per 1000. I can't catch it myself. I use: moxy, dagger, rx.

I know that this exception occurs when a collection is modified during an iteration. But I do not do that.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded (ActivityThread.java:4179)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1654)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: 
  at i.put (i.java:101)
  at fo.a (fo.java:44)
  at fm.onActivityPaused (fm.java:53)
  at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityPaused (Application.java:249)
  at android.app.Activity.onPause (Activity.java:1678)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPause (FragmentActivity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performPause (Activity.java:7158)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause (Instrumentation.java:1330)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded (ActivityThread.java:4168)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1654)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

I think an exception is due to this:

```
  at i.put (i.java:101)
  at fo.a (fo.java:44)
  at fm.onActivityPaused (fm.java:53)
```

Comment: Where is the CODE? How can we help you without some piece of code written?

Comment: The application is not small. I can't show all the code. And what exactly causes this exception, I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

You are using for each loop and at the same time you can't modify the list . Use for (int i ) based loop.